# Error running legacy node.js app with nvm and pm2

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2, nvm

### My Problem

I have an **old** nodejs app (runs under `v0.8.18`!) that I'd like to keep running for historical reasons. I can run it normally from the command line (i.e. `$ node app`), but I can't run it via pm2 (i.e. `$ pm2 start app`).

### Here's my setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

  - node `v0.8.18` installed for running the legacy app
  - node `v9.3.0` latest stable version with [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) installed globally
- App is reverse proxied through nginx (roughly following [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04))
- I have a config file `pm2.json` in the root folder of the app created [following this thread](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1034) that looks as follows:

```js
[{
  "name": "my-old-app",
  "exec_interpreter": "node@0.8.18",
  "script": "app.js",
  "error": "error.log"
}]
```

- Starting pm2 with:

```bash
$ NVM_DIR=/home/myusername/.nvm/ pm2 start pm2.json
```

yields:

```
$ NVM_DIR=/home/myusername/.nvm/ pm2 start pm2.json
[PM2][WARN] Applications my-old-app not running, starting...
[PM2] Setting Node to v0.8.18 (path=/home/myusername/.nvm/v0.8.18/bin/node)
[PM2] App [my-old-app] launched (1 instances)
┌─────────────────┬────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name        │ id │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ user       │ watching │
├─────────────────┼────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ my-old-app      │ 0  │ fork │ 5879 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 7.9 MB   │ myusername │ disabled │
└─────────────────┴────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

When I start try to start the app this way, here is the result of running `pm2 show my-old-app`

```
 Describing process with id 0 - name my-old-app
┌───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ errored                                          │
│ name              │ my-old-app                                       │
│ restarts          │ 15                                               │
│ uptime            │ 0                                                │
│ script path       │ /home/myusername/my-old-app/app.js               │
│ script args       │ N/A                                              │
│ error log path    │ /home/myusername/my-old-app/error-0.log          │
│ out log path      │ /home/myusername/.pm2/logs/my-old-app-out-0.log  │
│ pid path          │ /home/myusername/.pm2/pids/my-old-app-0.pid      │
│ interpreter       │ /home/myusername/.nvm/v0.8.18/bin/node           │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                              │
│ script id         │ 0                                                │
│ exec cwd          │ /home/myusername/my-old-app/                     │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                        │
│ node.js version   │ N/A                                              │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                │
│ created at        │ N/A                                              │
└───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Furthermore, the error that shows up repeatedly in `error-0.log` is:

```
domain.js:66
    throw er;
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'unref'
    at Object.PMX.init (/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/pmx.js:81:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

> **I don't know why this doesn't work.**

### What DOES Work

If I just run the app normally from the command line, it works perfectly as expected, i.e.

```
$ nvm use 0.8.18
Now using node v0.8.18 (npm v1.2.2)
$ node app
   info  - socket.io started
Express server listening on port 37426
```

It gets reverse proxied through nginx and is available in a browser via https://old.example.com. FYI, the contents of my nginx site config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/old.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/old.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

  server_name old.example.com;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # Pass requests for / to localhost:37426:
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:37426/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Clearly, I can't just use this setup because if the process is interrupted for any reason, it won't get restarted. Any ideas? I tried just running the app with node `v9.3.0` but the code is too old. It's also too extensive to just re-write in more up-to-date form.

Comment: Oddly, I can't find **_any_** files called `domain.js` at all anywhere either within my app or within the globally installed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. [`pm2` depends upon `pmx`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/70199f47f239b0ddb59a73bdc61a692cd4681b43/package.json#L176), which in turn uses the [`setTimeout().unref()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref). The `unref()` function was not added to nodejs until `v0.9.1`. Since I was trying to run my app with node `v0.8.18`, the `unref()` function was undefined hence the `Object #<Object> has no method 'unref'` error message.

Trying to run my app under newer node versions always failed, but eventually I realized it was always failing because of the same package: `bcrypt`. It turns out the original authors of this package had used a weird, buggy, in-between version of `bcrypt` (`v0.7.5`). When I switched it up to a slightly newer `bcrypt` (`v0.7.6`), I was able to run the entire app with node `v0.9.12`, which in turn, made it safe for `pm2` to use `unref()`.

### In Summary...

1. Don't try to use `pm2` to try to run node apps `<v0.9.1`, or
2. If you do, you'll likely need to modify the app so that it can be run with node `>=v0.9.1`

#### Update

One of the maintainers of `pm2` let me know that [they don't officially support any versions of nodejs `<v0.12` and soon they'll be dropping support for that as well](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1034#issuecomment-355511508).

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, it seems you are trying to run the app using node `v9.3.0`.

modify your command into something like this [ not tested ]

`NVM_DIR=/home/myusername/.nvm/ nvm use 0.8.18 && pm2 start pm2.json`

Comment: To be sure, I _am_ running `pm2` with `v9.3.0` but as you can see from the output I just added, the app is definitely being started with `v0.8.18`. Following your suggestion, though, I installed `pm2` under `v0.8.18` (i.e. `nvm use 0.8.18 && npm i -g pm2`) but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Oh! Actually I read the output wrong. Installing `pm2` under `v0.8.18` failed. 1pm2` appears to want `node >= 0.12`. So I tried `nvm install 0.12.18 && npm i -g pm2` and then tried to run the app (`node app`) unsuccessfully. Removed `node_modules` and tried to reinstall under `v0.12.18`. Still did not work. Version of `bcrypt` too old to work wtih `v0.12.18`.